# Duplicate tags: moon & moon-movie

Tags: discussion, tags

So it seems there are two tags for the 2009 movie Moon

[moon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moon)

[moon-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moon-movie)

And there's a lot of confusion as the former tag [moon] is a general tag as well as the movie tag.

Should [moon] be separated from the movie and all questions retagged appropriately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've altered the tags.

- [moon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moon) now reflects only the moon's status as Earth's satellite.
- [moon-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moon-movie) now reflects only the 2009 film starring Sam Rockwell.

Retagging may take some time.